# Redirecting to a URL on Highcharts marker click

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

How can I pass a third value (e.g. ID number) in a Highcharts time series so that I can open a new window based on it on marker click? [JsFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/9vb74u6a/4/)

I'm familiar with this method for a [simple chart](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-point-events-click-url/) with categories, but not for a time series.

Typically, a Highcharts time series accepts a series of arrays like `[1401285311000,1]`, which can be read in a click event with `event.point.options.x` and `event.point.options.y`.

Is there a way to add an `id`to each point, and then read it in a point's click event callback? I've tried passing it as a third value (Highcharts ignores it completely), or putting it under `id` after the two values (`[1401285311000, 1, id: {1}]`) which breaks the chart.

Any ideas?

```
// Replacing ajax call with a simple array for simplicity's sake
var data = [{"name":"Value","unit":"","data":[[1401285311000,5, 1],[1401288036000,10, 2],[1401289436000,8, 3],[1401291099000,15, 4]]}, {"name":"Value 2","unit":"","data":[[1401285311000,10, 1],[1401288036000,12, 2],[1401289436000,5, 3],[1401291099000,9, 4]]}]


$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'x'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Time Series'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: document.ontouchstart === undefined ?
                    'Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in' :
                    'Pinch the chart to zoom in'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            minRange: 14 * 24 * 3600 // fourteen days
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: ''
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
                        plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        lineWidth: 3,
                        marker: {
                            fillColor: null,
                            lineWidth: 2,
                            lineColor: null, // inherit from series

                        },
                        events:{
                                click: function (event, i) { 
                                   console.log(event.point);
                                }
                            }
                    },
                    line: {
                        dataLabels:{
                            enabled: false
                        }
                    },
                },

        series: data
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because it's time data doesn't mean you can't use [point objects](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data) instead of arrays:

```
var data = [{
    "name": "Value",
        "unit": "",
    "data": [
        {x: 1401285311000, y: 5, id: 1},
        {x: 1401288036000, y: 10, id: 2},
        {x: 1401289436000, y: 8, id: 3},
        {x: 1401291099000, y: 15, id: 4}
    ]
}, {
    "name": "Value 2",
        "unit": "",
        "data": [
        {x: 1401285311000, y: 10, id: 1},
        {x: 1401288036000, y: 12, id: 2},
        {x: 1401289436000, y: 5, id: 3},
        {x: 1401291099000, y: 9, id: 4}
    ]
}];
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9vb74u6a/5/).